# Query same column twice but on different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a SQL query that looks like below.

For my purpose I need to query the same price list twice, but for different articles. To do this I have joined the same table twice but using two aliases. Then selected the same column but with the prefix of the alias. There are also nested queries at the bottom to the same table to get the correct date from said list.

The query worked as intended until I tried to add the second table of the price list, using aliases "MC1" and "MC2". Now I get SQL error 203 "Column %1 in more than one table".

The code passes all the syntax checks I made so I am at a loss currently.

Any help is appreciated.

(I was not allowed to post a picture directly in the threat so it is a link)

SQL Query Code snapshot

[image]

Comment: Pictures don't help anyone. SQL code is text, and people prefer to see text here which is much easier to follow than a hard to read picture. And it seems you didn't alias the fields (MTWHLO exists in multiple tables?)

Comment: You need to disambiguate the columns by prefixing them with the alias of the source table.

Comment: Remove the `AS` before the table alias; it is not allowed in Oracle. You want `LEFT OUTER JOIN schema_name.table_name alias_name ON (...)`

Comment: I sincerely feel bad for you dealing with those completely non-descriptive table names and column names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your columns that you are selecting with the table alias.

As an example, if I had this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    someid     NUMBER,
    someval    VARCHAR2 (20)
);
```

I could query all of the columns like this

```sql
SELECT t1.someid,
       t1.someval,
       t2.someid,
       t2.someval
  FROM test_table t1 JOIN test_table t2 ON (t1.someid = t2.someid);
```